# Thumbnail Generation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a "good" way to generate a thumbnail for a JPEG file that doesn't have on in the EXIF information?

If a user uploads an image, I'm trying to display the thumbnail, but if there's no thumbnail in the image the display is blank (src=""). Currently we replace blank images with a loading image that gets swapped out with the thumbnail generated on the server by an AJAX call back.

Is there anything I can do client-side (jQuery & jQuery UI are already integrated, but open to new libraries if they'll help) other than displaying a loading image that gets changed by the AJAX call back?

For clarification I don't just mean taking the Base64 raw data and changing the height and width attributes most of our users upload 5MB+ files, and the text alone crashes the browser if we use the raw data. I mean actually appending a thumbnail to the EXIF, or creating it and using the created base64 data as the image source.

Apologies in advance for breaches in etiquette or lack of clarity, this is my first question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: weeping, cursing, and asking on StackOverflow. :)

In all sincerity I have no idea where to even start. I can get the raw data, but I'm not even sure how to parse it. I've only ever passed it to the img tag. I don't know what kind of algorithm would even generate a thumbnail.

Comment: Is the thumbnail generation taking too long? I don't understand what the issue is...

Comment: @Jason, I mean coding wise -- what have you tried (if anything)?

Comment: @SeanHanley, yes, but more specifically when multiple images are uploaded without EXIF, then there's a lot of placeholders on the page, and my boss doesn't like it.

Comment: You could post what you have on the backend to see if anyone has suggestions for improvement to make it more efficient. Or are you wanting to know if there is some kind of JS library that will generate the thumbnail on the client faster than your server can respond with one? Or are you unsure even how to generate a thumbnail on the server?

Comment: Getting Thumbnails from server, that I'm cool with, it was whether it was possible to generate an EXIF-style thumbnail (under 100k) that wouldn't be the 7mb of base64 encoding that a 5M jpg is when converted to raw data... putting all that text in the DOM crashes the browser when we try it, no matter what the height and width attributes are set to.

Comment: Basically some sort of image compression library would probably work, but handled client-side.